# How to build gtkparasite

Tags: application-development, gtk3, configure

i'm not able to build [gtkparasite](http://chipx86.github.io/gtkparasite/)

when i run:

```
./autogen.sh
```

i'm get this error

```
checking for GTK... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 >= 3.10.0 gtksourceview-3.0) were not met:

Requested 'gtk+-3.0 >= 3.10.0' but version of GTK+ is 3.6.1
Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GTK_CFLAGS
and GTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

So, when i do:

```
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

it show me a blank, line so i adjust it with:

```
$ locate pkg-config
/etc/bash_completion.d/pkg-config
/usr/bin/pkg-config
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/lib/npy-pkg-config
...........
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/bin/pkgconfig
```

but the error persist.

How I can do to build this sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Requested 'gtk+-3.0 >= 3.10.0' but version of GTK+ is 3.6.1

The program needs at least GTK+ v3.10 but you only have GTK+ v3.6.1

Ubuntu 14.04 will have GTK+ v.3.10. For other version of Ubuntu you need to either find a PPA or other unofficial packages for GTK+ v3.10 or compile it yourself, too (which includes compiling some more libs needed by GTK+).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I install a different versione of Gtk manually, i can break my system? My current Gtk remain the same?

Comment: Overwriting Ubuntu's version of GTK+ may cause trouble. Install your version into `/usr/local/` and set `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/` (or wherever the `gtk+*.pc` file for your GTK+ is)

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to compile manually, you have to install all the depenencies and -dev packages manually.

For gtk+ the command is

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev libgtksourceview-3.0-dev
```

You also need who knows what else. Check the README for dependencies and search for them and the -dev packages in the ubuntu database.